# ERROR: problem running ufw-init Bad argument `*nat'

Tags: linux, ufw, server-configuration

I was trying to make my server's firewall redirect port 8080/TCP to port 80/TCP. This is simply done by adding the lines before the COMMIT line to create a new *nat

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

However, after disabling and trying to enable ufw, I got this error

> ERROR: problem running ufw-init
> Bad argument `*nat' Error occurred at line: 75 Try` iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.

I had also enabled port forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf file by uncommenting the line #net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

-- before
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

--after
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Therefore, this is not the problem.

Comment: I still don't know why this is happening

Comment: I think I got a temporary fix. That is creating a new file to hold the redirection rule: I created the file /etc/ufw/before.rules.custom and added the line                                 
 ``` *nat :PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0] -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80 ```  Apply the new rule by running the following command:  ``` sudo iptables-restore < /etc/ufw/before.rules.custom ```

Answer (score 4):

No, its done after the COMMIT line, put it after the COMMIT line, add another COMMIT

```
# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT

# NAT table rules
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Forward traffic from port 8080 to port 80.
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80

COMMIT
```

disable ufw, enable ufw, and you good to go